# Error : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in cloneDeep

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

I have multiple schemas in my application, there could be duplicate type name but different properties. So I want to merge the types but sometimes there could be circular dependencies.

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep'
import { GraphQLObjectType } from 'graphql/type/definition'
import { mergeSchemas } from 'graphql-tools'

function mergeObjectTypes (leftType, rightType) {
  if (!rightType) {
    return leftType
  }
  if (leftType.constructor.name !== rightType.constructor.name) {
    throw new TypeError(`Cannot merge with different base type. this: ${leftType.constructor.name}, other: ${rightType.constructor.name}.`)
  }
  const mergedType = cloneDeep(leftType)
  mergedType.getFields() // Populate _fields
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rightType.getFields())) {
    mergedType._fields[key] = value
  }
  if (leftType instanceof GraphQLObjectType) {
    mergedType._interfaces = Array.from(new Set(leftType.getInterfaces().concat(rightType.getInterfaces())))
  }
  return mergedType
}

const schema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [schema1, schema2],
  onTypeConflict: (leftType, rightType) => {
    if (leftType instanceof GraphQLObjectType) {
      return mergeObjectTypes(leftType, rightType)
    }
    return leftType
  }
})
```

It throws an error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at isPrototype (D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:1354:21)
    at baseKeys (D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:965:8)
    at keys (D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:1706:56)
    at baseGetAllKeys (D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:926:16)
    at getAllKeys (D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:1152:10)
    at baseClone (D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:889:26)
    at D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:897:30
    at arrayEach (D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:140:9)
    at baseClone (D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:891:3)
    at D:\xyz\abc_new_gitlab\app\node_modules\lodash.clonedeep\index.js:897:30
```

Does anyone know How to resolve this ?

Comment: seems your leftType is circular object, try simplifying object by cloning only set of important objects inside leftType

Comment: @TGW Suppose if I have `type response { text: String }` and if same type exist in second schema then it is happening.

Comment: okay from what I understand from you question and comment is that if properties are different but type is same then you'll take all properties of that under that type, but while merging it gives you the above error?

Comment: @TGW yes correct